# How to set acknowledgement in case when retry gets exhausted in Kafka consumer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I have a Kafka consumer which retry 5 time and I am using Spring Kafka with retry template . Now if all retry are failed then how to does acknowledge work in that case . Also if i have set acknowledge mode to manually then how to acknowledge those message

Consumer

```
@Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(RetryTemplate retryTemplate) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    factory.setRecoveryCallback(context -> {
        log.error("Maximum retry policy has been reached {}", context.getAttribute("record"));
        Acknowledgment ack = (Acknowledgment) context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_ACKNOWLEDGMENT);
        ack.acknowledge();
        return null;
    });
    factory.setConcurrency(Integer.parseInt(kafkaConcurrency));
    return factory;
}
```

Kafka Listener

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.json}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void recieveSegmentService(String KafkaPayload, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws Exception {
    KafkaSegmentTrigger kafkaSegmentTrigger;
    kafkaSegmentTrigger = TransformUtil.fromJson(KafkaPayload, KafkaSegmentTrigger.class);
    log.info("Trigger recieved from segment service {}", kafkaSegmentTrigger);
    processMessage(kafkaSegmentTrigger);
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}
```

Comment: I have to get the acknowledgement also in the context but i am getting only consumer and record..How can i get that..Sharing config..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `RecoveryCallback` that handles the record when retries are exhausted, and you are NOT using manual acks, the container will commit the offset.

If you are using MANUAL acks, you can commit the offset in the recovery callback.

The context object passed to the callback has an attribute `RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_ACKNOWLEDGMENT` ('acknowledgment').

It also has `CONTEXT_CONSUMER` and `CONTEXT_RECORD`.

Comment: Also i am reading ..that we should use both sync() and async() commits ..When there is success we should use async() and when exception trigger then we call sync() commit..But in spring kafka template it use async() commit..How to set both sync and sync logic in my application..

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about; the template doesn't interact with the consumer at all. The container property `syncCommits` determines whether `commitSync()` or `commitAsync()` is called by the container. As I said in the answer, you have access to the `Consumer` as well in the recovery callback, so you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's unreadable; edit your question instead and comment that  you have done so. What is the point of getting the attributes if you do nothing with them?